# Set operations in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dataset that has the following structure

```
ID        PHASE  URL

1          1      url1
2          1      url2
3          1      url3
4          1      url4
5          2      url5
6          2      url3
7          2      url6
```

I want to find some sets of urls where it exists only in phase 1, both in phase 1 and 2 and only in phase 2. I think that I have to use some kind of set operators for this, but I do not know how? I will be very happy if someone can show me how to do this?

> I want to find out results of some set operations: for example phase1
>   intersect phase 2= url3, phase1 union phase 2url1, url2, url3, url4,
>   url5, url6, phase 2 minus phase 1=url 5 and url 6

I can create corresponding sets but I can neither show the contents of the sets or number of elements in the sets.

Best Regards

Ferda Özdemir Sönmez

Comment: On sheet place URL first and then Phase after that.. you will get required output

Comment: Hi,I added some comments, i want the result of some set operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a set based on a condition, right click on the underlying field in the data pane (left sidebar) and choose create set. Click on the condition tab, and enter your condition.

For example, to create a set of URLs that have at least one record with Phase=1, the condition can be `max([PHASE] = 1)`. You could name this set URLs_With_A_Phase_1.

You can then select two sets in the data pane that are based on the same field, and then choose Create Combined Set to create new sets based on the Union, Intersection etc of your previously defined sets.

Comment: Thank you Alex, After entering the question I managed to create the set and later created the combined sets (for intersections, etc.) using the same way you described. At this point, I need to show the number of items in multiple sets in a chart. I will enter it as a new question. Thank you again for your interest :)